# How to initialize the RootSagas with a call to an action with Redux, Sagas and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

**The problem:**
I got a simple login with Redux/Sagas/Typescript. I need to call a function whenever it hits a ProtectedRoute so I know if the token is valid (you know, basic auth stuff)...

***What I've got so far:***

```
import {
  all,
  AllEffect,
  ForkEffect,
  put,
  PutEffect,
  takeLatest,
} from 'redux-saga/effects';

import { Action } from 'redux';
import { LoginActions } from './login/types';
import { logInFailure, logInSubmit, logInSuccess, logout } from './login/sagas';
import { loginAuth } from './login/actions';
    
export default function* rootSaga(): Generator<
      AllEffect<ForkEffect<never> | PutEffect<Action<any>>>
    > {
      return yield all([
        takeLatest(LoginActions.LOGOUT, logout),
        takeLatest(LoginActions.LOGIN_SUBMIT, logInSubmit),
        takeLatest(LoginActions.LOGIN_SUCCESS, logInSuccess),
        takeLatest(LoginActions.LOGIN_FAILURE, logInFailure),
        put(loginAuth()),
      ]);
    }
```

However it won't call the function when I check on Redux Devtools. What the heck am I missing?

Comment: What is supposed to respond to the `loginAuth()` action? Is it supposed to kick off a saga? Right now it seems like an action should be dispatched but something needs to respond to that action. This is all assuming your root saga is set up to run properly.

Comment: Yup, as you can see on the last import, loginAuth is the action itself, the others are sagas. I just needed to run a saga whenever I go to a page so I can control the auth system.

Comment: If I dispatch it from DevTools it works properly btw.

Comment: I don't think the `put` belongs alongside the `takeLatest` like that.  But I'm not sure how exactly it's supposed to look.

Comment: So @LindaPaiste... I'm not sure as well lol. This is driving me crazy. I might just go back to context, I feel a bit more confident at least.

Comment: @GabeLeon yes saga can be very confusing.  You can probably do most of what you want with [`createAsyncThunk`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk).  What is the order of actions here supposed to be?  When do we dispatch `loginAuth`?

Comment: I've never dispatched an action directly from a root saga, but I do dispatch an action called APP_INIT when my main App component first mounts and run appropriate initialization sagas from there. So you may try that pattern instead of trying to dispatch from the root saga which may cause problems anyways if the component tree hasn't mounted and rendered yet when the root saga first runs.

Comment: Got the idea. Seems interesting! Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @LindaPaiste it would be dispatched when hitting a protected route, so I think azundo's idea would work best here. Good to know this is not a recommended pattern. Learned this pattern in a course, seems that they've got that one wrong lol Thank you all for everthing!